# Delete a premise & all data associated

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to delete a premise & all data associated to it. The flow should first find the premise then find all tasks associated to the premise, then find all steps associated to the tasks. It will delete all steps associated, then delete the tasks itself & finally deletes the premise itself.

However, my code seems to only able to delete the premise when there is no tasks & steps associated to it.

```
public async Task<ApiResponseBody> DeleteHMOPremiseAsync(string premiseId)
    {
        #region PremiseID check
        HMOPremises hmoPremises = await _unitOfWork.HMOPremisesRepository.GetByIDAsync(Guid.Parse(premiseId));

        if (hmoPremises == null)
        {
            return new ApiResponseBody
            {
                StatusDetail = new StatusDetail
                {
                    Code = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ErrorCodeBusiness.Failure).ToString(),
                    Title = "Failure",
                    Description = "Premise not found."
                }
            };
        }
        #endregion

        #region Authorization check
        if (hmoPremises.UserID != Guid.Parse((string)_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["UserId"]))
        {
            return GetUnauthorizedResponse();
        }
        #endregion

        #region Perform deletion for PremiseID

        List<HMOTask> getHMOTasks = (await _unitOfWork.HMOTaskRepository.GetNoLockAsync(e => e.PremisesID == Guid.Parse(premiseId))).ToList();
        if (getHMOTasks != null)
        {
            foreach (HMOTask task in getHMOTasks)
            {
                List<HMOStep> getHMOSteps = (await _unitOfWork.HMOStepRepository.GetNoLockAsync(e => e.TaskID == task.TaskID)).ToList();
                if (getHMOSteps != null)
                {
                    foreach (HMOStep step in getHMOSteps)
                    {
                        await _unitOfWork.HMOStepRepository.DeleteAsync(step.StepID);
                    }
                    await _unitOfWork.HMOTaskRepository.DeleteAsync(task.TaskID);
                }
            }
        }

        await _unitOfWork.HMOPremisesRepository.DeleteAsync(Guid.Parse(premiseId));

        await _unitOfWork.SaveAsync();

        return new ApiResponseBody();

        #endregion

#nullable disable
        }

    }



    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost("DeleteHMOPremise")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteHMOPremiseAsync(string premiseID)
    {
        try
        {
            return Ok(await _hmoService.DeleteHMOPremiseAsync(premiseID));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error($"HMOController - DeleteHMOPremiseAsync: {ex}");

            return BadRequest(
                new ApiResponseBody
                {
                    StatusDetail = new StatusDetail
                    {
                        Code = Convert.ToInt32(Enums.ErrorCodeBusiness.Failure).ToString(),
                        Title = "Failure",
                        Description = ex.Message
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    }
```